# When using Microsoft Test Manager 2010 with SfTS, how do QA engineers know what tests they have to run?

Tags: tfs, scrum, microsoft-test-manager

We are moving our projects to TFS 2010 using the [SfTS v3 (Scrum for Team System)](http://www.scrumforteamsystem.co.uk/ProcessGuidance/v3) template. We need to understand how Microsoft Test Manager is supposed to be used in **this** Scrum process.

*Specific scenario & question:*

The QA manager uses Test Manager to create Acceptance Test Work Items (WIs). These new WIs are created and "assigned to" him. The manager doesn't run all the tests, instead he wants to give that responsibility to his staff.

How is a QA engineer supposed to know that he has tests to run? Everything says it is assigned to the manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QA Manager has to create `Test Suites` at his `Test Plan` and then to assign `Testers` (QA Engineers) to each `Test Suite` that his wants to test.

Check this: [How to: Assign Who Will Run the Tests in a Test Plan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286739.aspx).

Comment: This might be what I need. do you know if the field "Testers" is connected to the WI in TFS? I'm sorry "connected" is the best word I can think of. There appears to be specific data stored in Test Manager that is not stored in TFS. I'm asking if "Testers" is one of those fields NOT stored in TFS.

Comment: No you cannot do that. `Work Items` from TFS (User Stories & Test Cases) are loaded in your Test Plan as different instances. They are just 'Test Suites' and 'Tests'. Their extra information (e.g. Testers, Configuration, Build ...) are not added in the Work Items on TFS.